# PHP sql- If row value equals this, then echo

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

Php-joomla database that inserts data. Each insert is new row. 
Every choice in dropdown box should do something after I press "submit", according to chosen value.
In the current state, what I want to do is that "if row value equals this, then do that. The way I did it is not working so far, it does not accept the "if row equals this then do this" statement, and always goes to "else". I have thought of "not equals" =! but this will not be practical for many choices in dropdown boxes.

edit: 
furthermore, the result of the array is

```
stdClass Object ( [FieldValue] => over 18 years)
```

How do i make only the "over 18 years" appear?

```
<?php

    // Get a db connection.
    $db = JFactory::getDbo();

    // Create a new query object.
    $query = $db->getQuery(true);

    // Select all records from the user profile table.
    // Order it by the ordering field.
    $query->select($db->quoteName(array(FieldValue)));
    $query->from($db->quoteName('tablevalues'));
    $query->where($db->quoteName('SubmissionId') . ' = '. $db->quote('2'));
    $query->and($db->quoteName('FieldName') . ' = '. $db->quote('age'));
```

//fieldname age is where age is stored. dropdown choices are 1.over 18 years 2. under 18 years.

```
    // Reset the query using our newly populated query object.
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $row = $db->loadObjectList();
    echo nl2br("\n");
    print_r($row['5']);
```

//5 is the "age" fieldbox. i will need to find a way to say "fieldname age" when i am done with the current issue. 
//furthermore, tried print_r($row['5'])FieldValue, still same result.

```
    echo nl2br("\n");
    if($row['5']=="over 18 years")
    {
        echo "5";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "10";
    }
    echo nl2br("\n");
```

//it always displays 10

```
    // Load the results as a list of stdClass objects (see later for more options on retrieving data).
    $results = $db->loadObjectList();
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say that `$row['5']` contains the value that you wish to check against.

> //5 is the "age" fieldbox

However, you are checking for equality against another field, i.e. `$row['27']`

It is not clear exactly what you are trying to achieve but there answers the question of why you always see it go into the `else` block and display `10`. I have no visibility of your data, but you should be addressing the field names correctly using the associative field names, i.e. $row['age'], to ensure you consistently target the correct field.

The `loadObjectList()` method with no args returns an array of rows, not a single row.

See docs here: https://docs.joomla.org/Selecting_data_using_JDatabase#loadObjectList.28.29

---

UPDATE

As you say that:

> the result of the array is
>
> `stdClass Object ( [FieldValue] => over 18 years)`

And you further enquire how to access this value, you access it like so (because this is an object, not an array).

`$row->FieldName`

Comment: Sorry, row '27' is the original code which i changed to post it here. Edited, please answer accordingly.
So, how to i return only the  row value, not the array?

Comment: @SolomonG see my update - if this helps please consider marking as accepted answer and upvote. Thanks.

Comment: Tried 
print_r($row['5])->FieldName; 
and print_r($row['5])->FieldValue;

Still same result. 
Also tried variations from     $results = $db->loadObjectList();
and it always displays an array.

Comment: `print_r($row['5])->FieldName` ? That is invalid php syntax. You should try with `echo print_r($row['5']->FieldName, true);`

Comment: Actual code is 
print_r($row['27'])->FieldValue;
which works, but still shows
stdClass Object ( [FieldValue] => over 18 years. )

Comment: Yes, the `print_r` is dumping out the value of `$row['27']`, then you are trying to access a property off the `print_r`. This should generate a syntax error in php but you might not have errors displayed?

Comment: You must access the property on the object directly - look carefully! `$row['5']->FieldName` or `$row['27']->FieldName`

Comment: @SolomonG sorted? Please can you also upvote my answer? :)

Comment: @SolomonG another tip - you don't need to use `echo nl2br("\n");`, you may as well just `echo '<br>';` - keep it simple

Comment: Thank you, removed print r it worked. I pressed "accepted answer", but upvote does not work because i have less than 15 reputation.

Now, for my next step, i will see how to build a score equation to increase score value according each dropdown choice, and make a thread for it :).

Comment: Good luck, it is better to check the Joomla / php.net docs for your answers. Keep making use of `var_dump()` and `print_r()` to inspect the data you are working with.